# How to get bytes of string in node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, byte

I want to read the size of bytes of a file as I read it. I have this

```
var path = 'training_data/dat1.txt';

var fs = require("fs"); //Load the filesystem module
var stats = fs.statSync(path);
var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];

var accSize = 0;

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path)
});
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    accSize += Buffer.byteLength(line, 'utf8');
    console.log(accSize + "/" + fileSizeInBytes);
});
lineReader.on('close', function() {
    console.log('completed!');
});
```

But it doesn't print out the correct filesize.

```
7/166
16/166
23/166
32/166
39/166
48/166
55/166
64/166
71/166
80/166
87/166
96/166
103/166
112/166
```

it prints this for example.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lineReader` doesn't include the newline `\n` character in the buffer as each line is read, which is where your bytes are missing.

Try this:

```
accSize += Buffer.byteLength(line + '\n', 'utf8');
```

**EDIT**

If the file being read uses Windows line endings, you'll need to add two characters, since those will also have a carriage return in addition to line feed, denoted as `'\r\n'`. ([see this for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))

Comment: It worked when I did + '\\n' (its actually 3 more characters for some reason), and then since the last line doesn't have a new line character, I just added 2 to the total size, and then in the end, it printed 168/168.

Comment: `'\n'` is actually a single character. By adding an additional `'\'`, you are escaping the other `'\'`, so instead of newline, you're using the literal string `'\n'`. In any case, if you needed to add two characters, it's probably because your document is formatted with windows line endings, which include a carriage return (`'\r\n'`). I'll add that to my answer